# unable to import ModalController

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying following code:

```
import { ModalController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

then modal controller display in red color as it doesn't get any reference and produces below error:

> unresolved type ModalController

I am new in angular2, so help me with the procedure to import modal controller in angular2 and how to use it?

Comment: have you try including one by one?? You app was imported or not?

Comment: yes,only modal controller is not imported,all others imported properly